# What is the connection with quadratic map

Tags: number-theory

While reading Prof. Tao's Wordpress blog. I noticed he mentioned a different function

> $\displaystyle\Lambda_2(n):= \sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\log^2(n/d)\ldots(\ast)$

and said that this function vanishes for numbers with more than two distinct prime factors and this follows from $x\mapsto x^2$ vanishes after being differentiated more that twice.

**But how can we reduce the expression $(\ast)$ to differentiating $x^2$? Or am I misunderstanding his statement?**

> [image]

[Here's the link to the blog.](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/the-prime-number-theorem-in-arithmetic-progressions-and-dueling-conspiracies/#lord-4)

Comment: I don't know about the differentiating, but here's what I'd try. Suppose $n$ has 3 distinct prime factors $p$, $q$, and $r$. Let $d$ be a divisor of $n$ not divisible by any of these, and consider the sum of the terms arising from the divisors $d,pd,qd,rd,pqd,prd,qrd,pqrd$.

Comment: There exists a concept of derivative of arithmetical function. See Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory, [p.45](http://books.google.com/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA45). Perhaps this might help. The identity (16) is called in that book *Selberg identity* and it is derived on page 46 (using this type of differentiation).

Answer (score 0):

If we take equation (2),
$$
\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)\approx x
$$
So aren't we just doing that with $\Lambda_2$?

$$
\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda_2(n)\approx x^2
$$

Specific examples:

$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda_2(6)&=\sum_{k=1,2,3,6}\mu(k)\log^2{\frac{6}{k}}\\
&=(\log3+\log2)^2-(\log^23+\log^22)\\
&=2\log2\log3
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda_2(30)&=\sum_{k=1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30}\mu(k)\log^2{\frac{30}{k}}\\
&=(\log5+\log3+\log2)^2-(\log3+\log2)^2-(\log5+\log2)^2-(\log3+\log5)^2\\&+\log^22+\log^25+\log^23\\&=0
\end{align}
$$

$\Lambda(abc\cdots d)=0$ where $a$, $b$, $c$ etc are distinct prime factors can be proved using the inclusion-exclusion principle.